# \newcommand - Include help / synopsis for my own command

Tags: macros, texstudio

I created a `\newcommand` with three arguments which does some nonesense. Now I want to have something like a docstring that helps me with the arguments once I forgot how I implemented it. Like in my IDE (TexStudio, btw.) I get the synopsis of standard commands on mouse-over. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\mycmd}[3]{\small#1~\large#2~\huge#3}
\begin{document}
    \mycmd{This}{is}{Nonsense!}
\end{document}
```

I now want to provide the synopsis, like `arg#1 will become small`, `arg#2 will become large` and `arg#3 will become huge`. Is that possible?

Comment: you mention texstudio in passing but this question is just about texstudio tex itself can not help here the help texts are editor specific (sorry I can't help with texstudio)

Comment: I think this page shows how to give the help text information for your command to texstudio https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/wiki/Frequently%20Asked%20Questions/#why-does-texstudio-mark-a-command-as-unrecognized

Comment: So this basically means that there is no "common" way of providing a command's synopsis like a `docstring` in Python?

Comment: that is correct

Comment: That's a pity. But well, thanks anyway. Would've loved it since I'm a huge fan of docstrings

Comment: You could embed the help in the command: `\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\hmycmd{Help for \textbackslash{}mycmd: \textbackslash{}small\#1\~{}\textbackslash{}large\#2~{}\textbackslash{}huge\#3}
\newcommand{\mycmd}[4][]{\ifx#1h\relax \hmycmd \else {\small#2~}{\large#3~}{\huge#4}\fi}
\begin{document}
    \mycmd{This}{is}{Nonsense!}

    \mycmd[h]{This}{is}{Nonsense!}
\end{document}`. Or later make a link??